# Control elements & Scrolling in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview

I am working on an app **in Swift** that will have a modally presented options panel. I have two issues, both related to UIScrollView.

## 1.

Because of the nature and size of the panel, I need to wrap it in a ScrollView so that if the device is in landscape mode, the content can scroll.

## 2.

The ScrollView appears to be intercepting all touch events to the Control elements contained within it. I have tried enabling and disabling user interaction, etc. I cannot get the control elements (buttons & sliders) to respond.

---

My structure is as seen here:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Your View which is the child view of your scrollView is userInteractionEnabled? You said you checked it for scroll view

Comment: Yes it's enabled. Every element has user interaction enabled. It's a very strange issue.

Comment: This is looking more and more like a bug. If I create a project with only a UIScrollerView, a UIView, and a UISlider, it works. If I add a height constraint, it breaks. If I add a UILabel to the UIView, it breaks. If I remove the constraints and UILabel, it stays broken until I delete the UISlider and re-add it.